# Creating a robust and scalable e-commerce solution / webapplication with J2EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am relatively new to web development.

I have a question i want to create the  e-commerce webapplication leveraging Java platform (J2EE).

first can some body share his experience *about available  open-source resources* for creating such web-application or open-source e-commerce solution, which is compatible with J2ee frameworks,

and if as i realize that ***there are only 1 or 2 vendor specific e-commerce solution available in Java***  then which J2EE frameworks or combination, i could use for creating my own e-commerce solution or web application,

while there are various options and alternatives available and it's difficult to choose one among them for each layer.

any tutorial/ resources.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How about this one called [Shopizer](http://www.shopizer.com/software-design/) ?  Though it is not based on the Jave EE platform ,it is built by using some popular java technologies nowadays such as Spring and Hibernate.

[image]

> The system heavily uses Spring IOC and Transaction annotations.
>   Business objects are Hibernate pojos retreived from an associated DAO
>   all grouped in a service facade exposed to Struts action classes and
>   modules. Shopizer supports HSQLDB, Oracle and MySQL databases.
>
> The system is built on Struts 2, Hibernate and Spring. It uses
>   Hibernate Search / Lucene for indexing and searching. Apache Commons
>   libraries are used for doing common routines. Reports are generated
>   using jasper reports. JQuery ui and ajax are heavily used on the ui as
>   well as DWR and Struts2-jQuery plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try [**apache ofbiz**](http://ofbiz.apache.org/). it is open source. it has range of features and active community.